# Checking for which submenu user clicked in android

Tags: android, submenu

I have created a submenu using the manifest file. I have four text fields in my submenu. I want to know which submenu item the user clicked. I know about the switch case item.getItemId condition for the menu items. But i want to know how to check for which submenu the user clicked. 
Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the id of the submenu item to a variable. For example:

```
int item;
@Override
public void onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
     case R.id.something: {
         this.item = something;
         return true;
     }
}
```

Now the variable item contains the id of the item selected.

Comment: that something is a submenu rite?